# #include "stdafx.h" Error for C++ Tutorial

Tags: c++, include, stdafx.h

I'm running a C++ calculator tutorial.

How do I solve the following errors regarding  "#include "stdafx.h""?

Errors:
"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "stdafx.h"  Calculator Tutorial C:\Users\user\source\repos\Calculator Tutorial\Calculator Tutorial\Calculator Tutorial.cpp  4   "

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory Calculator Tutorial C:\Users\user\source\repos\Calculator Tutorial\Calculator Tutorial\Calculator Tutorial.cpp  4   "

References:
https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/cpp-calculator/Debug

Comment: Try `#include "pch.h"` instead of `#include "stdafx.h"`

Comment: That's just changing the name of the header.

Comment: Correct. Using the windows console project template in a modern version of Visual Studio Community (or one of the paid versions) with precompiled headers enabled pch.h is the default name of the header generated for precompiled headers

Comment: If you have neither file in your folder because you created a project without precompiled headers you have to remove that include and most likely add #include <windows.h> and then fix the errors.